# OpenWebmail on Debian 5 (Perl 5.10)

Tags: debian, perl, mod-perl

I've upgraded server running OpenWebmail from Debian 4.0 to Debian 5.0. Perl was upgraded to 5.10 as well. I have issues with some functions of OpenWebmail (attachments are 0 bytes size, HTML-formatted e-mails are broken), may be there is some patch for Openwebmail or compatibility mode for Perl?

Answer (score 0):

ask on the OpenWebMail mailing list, and include your OpenWebMail version number:

http://openwebmail.acatysmoof.com/archive

Comment: It seems that mailing list is down... :(